# CMD script: copy a file and rename it

Tags: batch-file, cmd

I have to write a simple CMD script, its task is to copy a file from one folder to another. User have to enter source and destination path and the name of the file. Script has to add "_copy" to the name of copied file. I only know how to add a suffix to the file after file extension but it's not what I need.

I was trying it with `%~n1` and `%~x1` but it didn't work properly. Can someone help me solve this problem?

```
@echo off
echo Source path
set /P folder1=
echo File name
set /P file1=
echo Destination path
set /P folder2=

if %folder1% == %folder2% goto path
if exist %folder2%\%file1% goto exist

set file2=%file1%
set "file2=%~dpn1_copy%~x1"

copy %folder1%\%file1% %folder2%\%file2%
goto end

:exist
echo File exist in destination folder
goto end

:path
echo Destination and source paths are the same
goto end

:end
```

Comment: Replace `set file2=%file1%`, `set "file2=%~dpn1_copy%~x1"`, and `copy %folder1%\%file1% %folder2%\%file2%`, with `For %%G In ("%file1%") Do Copy "%folder1%\%%~G" "%folder2%\%%~nG_copy%%~xG"`. You can also remove the line `:end`, and change all instances of `goto end` with `GoTo :EOF`.

Comment: You should also improve `if %folder1% == %folder2% goto path`, and `if exist %folder2%\%file1% goto exist` by protecting possible poison characters and spaces with doublequotes. i.e. `If /I "%folder1%" == "%folder2%" GoTo path` and `If Exist "%folder2%\%file1%" GoTo exist`.

Comment: Thanks for your answer but in this task I shouldn't use "for" loop, because I have to use it in next exercise.

Comment: Of course you can still use a `for` loop! Just change `Copy "%folder1%\%%~G" "%folder2%\%%~nG_copy%%~xG"` to `Set "file2=%%~nG_copy%%~xG"`. Then you can use the variable as you'd intended, i.e. `Copy "%folder1%\%file1%" "%folder2%\%file2%"`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`%1` (first argument from input) never get's set, you need to set it. In this case use `call` to set it.

```
@echo off
set /p "sourcep=Source path: "
set /p "sourcef=File: "
set /p "destp=Destination path: "
if "%sourcep%" == "%destp%" echo source and destination is the same & goto :EOF
if exist "%destp%\%sourcef%" echo %sourcef% already exists in %destp% & goto :EOF
call :work "%sourcef%"
goto :EOF
:work
if not exist "%destp%\%~n1_copy%~x1" (
      copy "%~f1" "%destp%\%~n1_copy%~x1"
) else (
      echo "%destp%\%~n1_copy%~x1" already exists
)
```

You can also use the search/replace method, but that would include either using `delayedexpansion` or by adding some escaping to your variables:

```
@echo off & setlocal enabledelayedexpansion

set /p "sourcep=Source path: "
set /p "sourcef= File: "
set /p "destp=Destination path: "
set "ext=%sourcef:*.=%"
set "file=!sourcef:.%ext%=!
if "%sourcep%" == "%destp%" echo source and destination is the same & goto :EOF
if exist "%destp%\%sourcef%" echo %sourcef% already exists in %destp% & goto :EOF
if exist "%destp%\%file%_copy.%ext%" echo "%destp%\%file%_copy.%ext%" already exists & goto :EOF
copy "%sourcep%\%sourcef%" "%destp%\%file%_copy.%ext%"
```

Comment: Thanks for your help, I used first solution and everything works ;) I have to read more about it.

Comment: 100%, all of the help for each command is available if you open `cmd` and run each command with a trailing `/?` for example `if /?`, `set /?` and more importantly in this instance, `call /?`